# NuGet a element with the same key was already added

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package-restore

I want to install the WebOptimizaton-Package to a recently new added project of my solution using the packet-manager command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Project MyNewProject
```

In the console he is telling me that all dependencies were downloaded and added. After the main package is installed, it will throw an installation error:

> "Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3" was successfully installed on "MyNewProject"
>
> Installation error. We will do a rollback now...

Then he removes the package with all dependencies and throw the following error:

> Install-Package: An element with the same key was already added. 
>   At Line 1 Char 1: + Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Project MyNewProject
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

I already tried deleting the subfolder in the packages-folder but it's not working. It seems that NuGet will download the package and then he's wondering that it is there and will remove it. But the package isn't existing in the NuGet GUI, packages.config or the references.

I also tried to uninstall the package with and without -Force parameter. But this is not working too because then NuGet tell me that the package isn't existing.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 8.1.